# Cross-compile from Swift to Android?

Tags: java, android, swift3, cross-compiling

I've read about that in several articles (compilers like Silver, Fire, etc), but my specific question is just the following:

I'm an iOS developer. I've finished a simple app in Swift and uploaded it to the App Store. Is it possible to cross-compile the app so that I get an Android app?

I know this isn't that easy, but according to the articles, there are ways to do this. 
What would you say, what is the easiest and most effeicient way to do "convert" a Swift app to ak Android/Java app?

Comment: You can compile Swift on Android quite easily, but that's not the issue. The issue is that UIKit is an iOS specific framework. You would have to write a new UI layer that uses the Android SDK. Unfortunately, the Android SDK is in Java, so you would have to call it through the Android NDK, which is a toooootttttttal bitch to do.

Answer (score 0):

With my little knowledge I don't think it works like that, an app is a package of executables and assets, moving from one platform to another is not possible.
What you can try, write a Swift program(not an app), cross compile for android kernel and then run on its kernel(android is Unix based after all)